# How to remove all html tags except italics and keep newline information using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following `data` that I wish to strip all html elements except italics (`<i>`) and newline (`\n`) information using `Beautifulsoup`. I've tried multiple algorithms only to remain unsuccessful. The original `data`:

```
data = '<div><div><i><font color=""#ff086c"">Tip: amplitude is decreased in axonal neuropathies; CV&nbsp;</font></i><i><font color=""#ff086c"">&amp; latency are</font></i><i><font color=""#ff086c"">&nbsp;prolonged in&nbsp;demyelination</font></i></div></div><div><i><font color=""#ff086c""><br></font></i></div><font color=""#ff086c""><i>1. Onset latency:</i>&nbsp;</font>is the time required for an electrical stimulus to initiate an evoked potential. This reflects the conduction along the fastest fibers.&nbsp;<div><i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i><br><div><div><br></div><div><font color=""#ff086c""><i>2. Peak latency:</i>&nbsp;</font>represents the latency along the majority of the axons and is measured at the peak of the waveform amplitude.&nbsp;</div><div><i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i>'
```

I attempted to get all text alone, but I lost the italics information:

```
print(BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser').get_text('\n'))
```

I attempted to split the data using (`<div>`) tags, but this leads to random lines being duplicated:

```
for element in [i.get_text().replace('\xa0', ' ').lstrip().rstrip() for i in BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser').find_all('div')]: print(element)
```

The data should eventually look like this:

> *Tip: amplitude is decreased in axonal neuropathies; CV & latency
> are prolonged in demyelination*
>
> *1. Onset latency:* is the time required for an electrical
> stimulus to initiate an evoked potential. This reflects the conduction
> along the fastest fibers.  *- Prolonged in demyelination.*
>
> *2. Peak latency:* represents the latency along the majority of
> the axons and is measured at the peak of the waveform amplitude.  *-
> Prolonged in demyelination.*

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can share a page link

Comment: What page? This is not from a page, it's actually an Anki deck card with the html information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is that plain text do not support formatting, so if you like to keep something formated it needs some markup.

> strip all html elements except italics () and newline (\n)

You could `unwrap()` with `BeautifulSoup` but be aware there are no line breaks like `\n` just tags `<br>`:

```
for e in soup.find_all():
    if e.name not in ['br','i']:
        e.unwrap()
```

###### Example

Think closest result you could get without any regex is something like this - keep in mind that `i` as markup is staying in place.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div><div><i><font color=""#ff086c"">Tip: amplitude is decreased in axonal neuropathies; CV&nbsp;</font></i><i><font color=""#ff086c"">&amp; latency are</font></i><i><font color=""#ff086c"">&nbsp;prolonged in&nbsp;demyelination</font></i></div></div><div><i><font color=""#ff086c""><br></font></i></div><font color=""#ff086c""><i>1. Onset latency:</i>&nbsp;</font>is the time required for an electrical stimulus to initiate an evoked potential. This reflects the conduction along the fastest fibers.&nbsp;<div><i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i><br><div><div><br></div><div><font color=""#ff086c""><i>2. Peak latency:</i>&nbsp;</font>represents the latency along the majority of the axons and is measured at the peak of the waveform amplitude.&nbsp;</div><div><i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.find_all():
    if e.name == 'div':
        e.append(soup.new_tag('br'))

    if e.name not in ['i','br']:
        if len(e.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
            e.extract()
        else:
            e.unwrap()

print(str(soup).replace('<br/>','\n'))
```

###### Output

```
<i>Tip: amplitude is decreased in axonal neuropathies; CV </i><i>&amp; latency are</i><i> prolonged in demyelination</i>

<i>1. Onset latency:</i> is the time required for an electrical stimulus to initiate an evoked potential. This reflects the conduction along the fastest fibers. <i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i>
<i>2. Peak latency:</i> represents the latency along the majority of the axons and is measured at the peak of the waveform amplitude. 
<i>- Prolonged in demyelination.</i>
```